# How can I allow user to input multiple lines when prompted to in Python? When Enter is pressed or /n is used in an input, it does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im relatively new to Python and have been trying to make a program where you can input multiple lines of integers for the program to process and return. However, my problem is that during Input, you can only type 1 line of integers. Im not looking to solve this problem through text files, but rather by user typing in multiple lines in 1 input. Anyone can guide me through this?

I have tried inserting /n when typing in the input, but it does not read it for some reason.

test_cases = input('How many test cases for the program?')
x = input("Type each test case values in a separate line")

Sample Input
3
12 0 41 
0 22 2
3 2 44

Output
36 0 123
0 66 6
6 4 132